# jQuery add close to each table row starting again for each table

Tags: jquery, class, html-table

I am using the following script to add a unique class to each row of a table. Works nicely. However if I have more than one table there's a problem. If the first table has 50 rows then the first row of the second table starts at 51. Not what I am after. Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table').each(function() {
        $('table tbody > tr').each(function() {   
            var rcount = 1;
            $("tr").attr("class", function() {
                return "row" + rcount++;
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `$('table tbody > tr')` with `$(this).children('tbody > tr')` and `$("tr")` with `$(this)`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table').each(function() { 
        $(this).children('tbody > tr').each(function() {
            var rcount = 1; 
            $(this).attr("class", function() { 
                return "row" + rcount++; 
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Afraid that code doesn't give me any classes at all, tried modifying mine then copying your exactly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did it this way in the end:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table').each(function() {
        var rcount = 1; 
        $(this).find('tr').each(function() {
            $(this).attr("class", function() { 
                return "row" + rcount++; 
            });
        });
    });
});
```